# Will System.Data.Spatial DBGeography.Distance() will work with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, dbgeography

I am using `System.Data.Spatial.DBGeography.Distance()` to calculate distance between two `DBGeography` locations using LINQToSQL, c#. I verified this is working with SQL Server 2012. Can I use same with SQL Server 2008.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am in situation where I don't have access to SQL Server 2008. So want to know if I can use this or not.

Comment: Yes, they will work with SQL Server 2008

Comment: Thanks Erik. It will work with SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent method of `System.Data.Spatial.DBGeography.Distance()` in SQL Server is `Geography.STDistance()`.
I have tested `STDistance` method in SQL Server 2008 and it is working good.

Everyone, Thanks for the response!